# How to fix the problem that Gensim not working with pattern3?

Tags: python, design-patterns, gensim

I'm working with Gensim to extract keywords from HTML or text.
My environment is **Centos 7 / Python 3.6 / Pip3**.
After checking Gensim source code, I found that Gensim Keywords API in Summarization module depends on pattern.

**Keywords.py:**

`def keywords(text, ratio=0.2, words=None, split=False, scores=False, pos_filter=('NN', 'JJ'),lemmatize=False, deacc=True):`

The pos_filter and lemmatize feature depend on pattern.
If no pattern module avaiable, pos_filter is set to None, no filtering.

**textcleaner.py:**

HAS_PATTERN is set by pattern.en module.
In my system, only pattern3 is available, **pattern is only available for python2.7.**

How to fix this problem?

Comment: Please provide (MRE)[https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example]. How did you get to know that `gensim` has a dependency on `pattern` in version for `Python-2.7`?

Answer (score 0):

The summarization functionality in Gensim is sufficiently ornery & idiosyncratic in its dependencies & behavior that it is being removed from the next (4.0.0) Gensim release.

You may want to seek alternate means of identifying keywords, depending on your exact needs. What's your ultimate goal?

If you have reason to believe the specific algorithms in the gensim-3.8.3 `summarization` module are beneficial for your needs, you might want to extract their key analyses into your own code without the same dependencies. (For example, if you think part-of-speech tagging is a crucial step for your application, you might choose to use POS-tagging from NLTK or SpaCy instead.)

Comment: My ultimatet goal is to keyword extraction with fully gensim implementation, including POS-tagging, set pos-filter as 'NN' to filter non-NOUN keywords.
Seems that the only way is to replace pattern.en.tag with NLTK or SpaCy.

Comment: What's the goal after that - how are these all-noun keywords going to be useful for some task? (I do suspect that using some more modern POS-tagger, like that in SpaCy, and then some simple statistical ranking of the remaining nouns/noun-phrases will likely work as well or better than the old Gensim code - as its keyword ranking was only using some very simple statistics, as well.)